# How generate play application with default SBT layout

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-stack

How to create new play application template with default sbt layout?

I can set `disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin)` in `build.sbt` on exiting app, but I want generate template from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [Activator](https://www.typesafe.com/activator/download), you can use the [play-sbt-layout-seed template](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-sbt-layout-seed) to create an application using the [default SBT layout](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anatomy#Default-SBT-layout). In order to do that, just run the following command:

```
activator new your-project-name play-sbt-layout-seed
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally created a Giter8 template specifically for this.

You can do:

```
sbt new muya/play-sbt-scala-seed.g8
```

https://github.com/muya/play-sbt-scala-seed.g8

Comment: Does this layout actually work in production? I mean, here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Anatomy#Default-SBT-layout, the docs state that the support is still experimental

Comment: @sentenza We have been using this successfully in production in Play 2.6 . (Scala). I'll take some time to make sure it works with 2.7 also.

Comment: Thanks @muya_. I would really like to switch to the default SBT layout.

Answer (score -1):

u need to download play zip package as set path in environment variables and from command prompt execute play new YourApplication

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/NewApplication